# Flask-ask not recognizing SSML in YAML file and outputting plain text response

Tags: python, flask, alexa-skills-kit, ssml

Below is a response template in my templates.yaml file:

```
entity_paused: <speak>I paused {{ entity }} <say-as interpret-as="digits">{{ id }}</say-as></speak>.
```

According to the flask-ask [documents](http://flask-ask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/responses.html#automatic-handling-of-plaintext-and-ssml), they automatically detect SSML based on the root element 'speak'. Yet when I test my app, Alexa readys the template varbatim and I can see the response sent back to the Alexa service is Plaintext type.
I believe the SSML is correct according to the Amazon [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference#say-as)

I call the template via:

```
return statement(render_template('paused_entity', entity='SomeEntity', id=123456))
```

Apologies in advance if this is something basic as I've only been coding for 7 months. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was in *.../flask_ask/models.py* file.
Scroll down to *def _output_speech(speech):* function and replace:

```
xmldoc = ElementTree.fromstring(speech)
    if xmldoc.tag == 'speak':
```

with:

```
if '<speak' in speech:
```

Easy and works...

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone finds this in the future, the originally supplied template is correct. Not sure why I had to copy and re-paste it but there was some weird unindent error.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with this too and found that I needed to restart the FlaskAsk instance before it would detect changes with my templates.yaml file.

Comment: Short answers such as this one are generally better suited as comments.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the string of the yaml has been loaded as unicode.

```
- <speak> Schön dich zu sehen! </speak>
```

I fixed it by encoding the unicode to normal string.

```
alexa_speaks.encode('utf-8')
```

Now amazon recognizes the sentences in my yaml file correct as ssml.